# Copy specific subfolders from multiple folders in bulk

Tags: command-line

I have hundreds of folders all structured the same way:

```
g:\Collections\001\p
g:\Collections\001\a
g:\Collections\001\m

g:\Collections\002\p
g:\Collections\002\a
g:\Collections\002\m

g:\Collections\003\p
g:\Collections\003\a
g:\Collections\003\m
```

and so on.

Is there anyway to copy just the "m" folders and their contents into a second collections folder, say "Collections2", while still retaining the same folder structure. What I want to end up with is:

```
g:\Collections2\001\m
g:\Collections2\002\m
g:\Collections2\003\m
g:\Collections2\004\m
```

Alternatively, if I just make a copy of the entire collection folder is there anyway to delete all the "p" and "a" folders and their contents.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After tried a lot, I have found a solution:

```
cd g:\collections
for /d %i in (*) do (
    md g:\collections2\%i\m
    xcopy /e %i\m g:\collections2\%i\m\
)
```

Run that in the command prompt (if you run it in a batch you need to replace %i -> %%i)